# What is the definitive JSON request format for optional values, optional section of values, optional array of values?

Tags: json

I am developing a REST/JSON API. There are many ways an optional value can be presented in a JSON POST/PUT request.

Q1. What is the best way to present optional field values in JSON request if API client doesn't want to specify them?

Password is optional : OPTION 1

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "username": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "password": null
  }
}
```

Password is optional : OPTION 2

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "username": "john.doe@acme.com",
  }
}
```

Password is optional : OPTION 3

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "username": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "password": ""
  }
}
```

Q2. What is the best way to present optional set field values in JSON request if API client doesn't want to specify them?

Credentials are optional : OPTION 1

```
{
  "credentials": null,
  "attributes": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
  }
}
```

Credentials are optional : OPTION 2

```
{
  "credentials": {},
  "attributes": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
  }
}
```

Credentials are optional : OPTION 3

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
  }
}
```

Credentials are optional : OPTION 4

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "username": null,
    "password": null
  },
  "attributes": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com"
  }
}
```

I am using RestEasy in Java as API server and a RubyonRails website as client.

Comment: You can do any of them, but I think the cleanest is to simply leave out the name/value pair.  Using `null` and `""` creates problems for many programming environments.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is the same in both cases: It's up to you, but the most common approach is to leave the key off entirely. Nothing says "nothing" like being completely absent.

Comment: There is certainly a difference in semantics between `{foo: ""}` and `{foo: null}` in the java world. I'd argue against `{foo: ""}` and for `{}` in this case.

Comment: @atamanroman: The semantics are different full stop, I'd say, not just in the Java world.

Comment: yes of course! I tried to say (and failed) that the three mentioned variants are quite different. Some programming environments, however, may not distinguish between them (java has no undefined, oracle treats "" as null, ..) so one has to be careful which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

after analize your question.. i guess that your first option (1 edited "" instead of null)

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "username": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "password": ""
  }
}
```

Is the best way, you could use other but this is most easy to read and parse... i coud use value password  " " instead of null... in code you can validate if (password == "") and that would be all...

Hope you can resolve this whith my answer...

Regards...

Comment: I'd argue against this version.  Many language environments have trouble dealing with a literal null, and handling it becomes awkward.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

[T.J. Crowder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343945/4445260) in other words:

Every object theoretically contains every possible key, but you just write down those keys that actually have a value. Hence, every member of an object is in fact an optional.

In your case,

- for `password`, take option 2 or alternatively option 1,
- if `credentials` is optional, take option 3 or alternatively option 1,
- if `credentials` is required, take option 2 or alternatively option 4.

Using `""` for an empty password is to be discouraged, as you also wouldn't use 0 for an unknown age.

JSON is just a simple data format whose usage is up to the user. If you want to have a specific structure, you have to define it in the software that is using the data. Still, you can keep it clean by applying a consistent structure.

### Long answer

Consider a few further things:

1. The syntax for JSON arrays is just syntactic sugar for a object,
   that assigns a value to each consecutive index, starting at 0:

   ```
   [ "alpha", "beta" ]
   ```

   contains the same information as

   ```
   { "0": "alpha", "1": "beta"}
   ```

   Obviously, there are implementation details and limitations to
   consider, but on an abstract level, you can ignore them.
2. On the other hand, objects are more flexible, as they can jump over indices, which you can't with arrays:

   ```
   { "1": "beta"}
   ```
3. `null` is just a placeholder for optional members, where you explicitely want to tell the key but don't have a value to assign to it.
4. Optional members are just special kinds of arrays, with either 0 or 1 elements.

For arrays, the concept of empty or present is more intuitive:

```
// array is empty
{
    "data": []
}

// array contains entries
{
    "data": ["123", "456"] // indices 2, 3, ... are not present
}
```

Substituting the array by an object as described above, we get:

```
// optional member is empty
{
    "data": {}
}

// optional member is present
{
    "data": {
        "0": "132",
        "1": "456",
        // keys 2, 3, ... are not present
    }
}
```

Having nested information, you need to apply the concept multiple times. Let's start with arrays of arrays:

```
// array of arrays is empty
{   
    "data": []
}

// array of arrays contains empty array
{   
    "data": [[]]
}

// array of arrays contains present and empty arrays
{   
    "data": [   
        ["123", "456"],
        ["789"],
        []
    ]
}
```

Substituting ...

- ... the outer arrays by objects:

  ```
  // optional array is not present
  {   
      "data": {} 
  }

  // optional array contains empty array
  {   
      "data": { "0": [] } 
  }

  // optional array contains filled and empty arrays
  {
      "data": { 
          "0": ["123", "456"],
          "1": ["789"],
          "2": []
      }
  }
  ```
- ... the inner arrays by objects:

  ```
  // array of optionals is empty
  {   
      "data": []
  }

  // array of optionals contains empty optional
  {   
      "data": [{}]
  }

  // array of optionals contains present and empty optionals
  {
      "data": [
          { "0": "123", "1": "456" },
          { "0": "789" },
          {}
      ]
  }
  ```
- ... all arrays by objects:

  ```
  // optional optional is not present
  {
      "data": {}
  }

  // optional optional contains empty optional
  {
      "data": { 0": {} }  
  }

  // optional optional contains present and empty optionals
  {
      "data": {
          { "0": "123", "1": "456"},
          { "0": "789"},
          {}
      }
  }
  ```

Now, point 2 allows us to use actual keys and also ommit the ordering.

This leads to the answer:

- If point 3 (using null as placeholder) does not apply:

  - for `password`, take option 2,
  - if `credentials` is optional, take option 3,
  - if `credentials` is required, take option 2.
- If point 3 applies:

  - for `password`, take option 1,
  - if `credentials` is optional, take option 1,
  - if `credentials` is required, take option 4.